# IntelliJ IDEA Plugin development, how can I get the MavenProjectsManager instance?

Tags: intellij-plugin

How can I get the MavenProjectsManager instance?

1. Is there a service, component or something else that goes in the plugin.xml to instantiate the MavenProjectsManager instance?

   MavenProjectsManager manager = MavenProjectsManager.getInstance(project);

My plugin.xml file so far:

```
<idea-plugin version="2">
    <id>com.arcbees.plugin.idea</id>
    <name>GWT-Platform (GWTP) IntelliJ IDEA Plugin</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <vendor email="support@arcbees.com" url="http://www.arcbees.com">ArcBees</vendor>

    <description><![CDATA[
      The GWTP IDEA plugin provides tools for GWT-Platform framework in IntelliJ IDEA.<br>
      ]]></description>

    <change-notes><![CDATA[
      Project Creation by Archetype added (8/30/2013).<br>
      ]]>
    </change-notes>

    <!-- please see http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/Build+Number+Ranges for description -->
    <idea-version since-build="107.105"/>

    <depends>org.jetbrains.idea.maven</depends>

    <application-components>
    </application-components>

    <project-components>
    </project-components>

    <actions>
    </actions>

    <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">

        <moduleType id="GWTP_CREATE_PROJECT_MODULE"
                    implementationClass="com.arcbees.plugin.idea.moduletypes.CreateProjectModuleType"
                    classpathProvider="true"/>

        <wizardMode implementation="com.arcbees.plugin.idea.wizards.createproject.CreateProjectWizard"/>

    </extensions>

</idea-plugin>
```

Comment: You need to access it via code, right? MavenProjectsManager doesnt seem to be in openapi.jar - is it part of another jar, for example perhaps the Maven plugin?

Comment: I found I had to add the maven.jar to the SDK jar list to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the community version
2. If on a mac, Show package contents of the Community Version
3. Open the package, seek out the plugins directory with the maven plugin jar.
4. Add that jar to a location where you can remember it in the file system.
5. Goto the plugin, open module settings.
6. Goto the SDK's and find the IntelliJ IDEA SDK and add the maven jar to the SDK jar list.