# Accessing a built in intelij plugin from another plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm writing an InteliJ plugin, and one of the things it is required to do is add a maven dependency to a project if it doesn't exist already. I've found a [unit test](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/maven/src/test/java/org/jetbrains/idea/maven/dom/MavenModelReadingAndWritingTest.java#L71-L98) in InteliJ that does what I want to do, which serves as an example, but I can't figure out how to access the org.jetbrains.idea.maven.dom in my project.

I tried following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19015676/3408), and that meant that auto-complete etc. worked and I was able to write the code, but when I tried to compile it, I got:

```
error: package org.jetbrains.idea.maven.dom does not exist
import org.jetbrains.idea.maven.dom.MavenDomUtil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please declare dependency on Maven plugin as described here http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/plugin_structure/plugin_dependencies.html